# Google Maps API v3 - Can't create position marker

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Trying to do a simple position marker on a Google map imbed. Everything looks right, but not working.

```js
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css"/>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script>
      function initialize() {
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.0501322,-82.914233),
          zoom: 13,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
      }
      
      
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
      
       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({  
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.0496714,-82.9121331),  
      map: map  
    });          
    </script></head>
```

The map is loading fine, but no marker is found.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the marker inside the initialize function (where the map variable exists).

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.0501322, -82.914233),
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.0496714, -82.9121331),
    map: map
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to initialize the marker object inside the initialize() method of the code. One way is how geocodezip has demoed. Here is one more way if you want to write modular code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // Standard google maps function
    function initialize() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.0501322, -82.914233);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 12,
            center: myLatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        TestMarker();
    }

    // Function for adding a marker to the page.
    function addMarker(location) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            map: map
        });
    }

    // Testing the addMarker function
    function TestMarker() {
           GoldenGatePark = new google.maps.LatLng(37.7699298, -122.4469157);
           addMarker(GoldenGatePark);
    }
</script>
```

Here you have added a marker in the *TestMarker function* and the *TestMarker function* is called in the *initialize()* method. You can just change the values of *LatLng* in the *TestMarker function* code.